# How to handle a double insert in Spring/Hibernate

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I have to add an entity(User) in a table (User).
If the insert is correctly done, I have to know the ID (Autoincrement field) of the last user inserted and use it to insert some values in another table (Role).

If some problems occur when I make the insert into Role table, I have to delete even the record previously inserted into User table. In other words, my tables must match.

What's the right way to handle this issue with Spring and Hibernate? I'm a beginner to both.

```
    User                            Role
-------------                -------------------
Id | Username                Id_user |  Role  
-------------                -------------------
 1 | Mark                       1    | Admin
 2 | Bob                        2    | User 
--------------               -------------------
 /\                            /\
  ------------------------------
```

I was trying something like this, but when I try to "manually" make a rollBack() (just to understand how it works), I get and error (**Transaction not successfully started**)

```
    ..........
    try{
        Session session = getHibernateSession();
        session.beginTransaction();           
        session.saveOrUpdate(utente);         
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.getTransaction().rollback(); /// here I was try to "manually" rollback
        HibernateUtil.shutdown();
    }
    catch(Exception e){ 
        ......              
    }
```

Comment: You need to read more about transactions (units of work). Both rollaback and commit finish a current transaction. Regarding your question -you just need to perform all the actions in one transaction. In this case the both actions will be successful or rolled back (if any errors occur).

Comment: You may also need to read more about hibernate (and/or Jpa) since you use it. A use case like this is why orm frameworks exist. You just need make a one-to-many association from user to role, and save/persist the user inside a transaction. Everything else is handled by the framework.